# Вёрстка html-письма: почему в gmail и yandex не работают медиазапросы?

Tags: html, вёрстка, gmail, яндекс-почта

Сделал вёрстку письма на foundation for emails, заинлайнил стили, собрал шаблон, но в итоге медиазапросы не проходят в gmail и yandex, хотя в офф.блоге gmail утверждают, что они поддерживают медиазапросы с сентября.
Не подскажете в чём может быть проблема?
Тестировал через putsmail (Litmus).
Возможно, это я просто в Litmus что-то не так выставил, т.к. если посмотреть код письма в почтовом ящике - всё выглядит так, как будто просто тег с медиазапросами не добавился к шаблону.

Видел похожие вопросы в блогах гугла, но не видел ответов.

Судя по этому списку поддерживаемых свойств, медиазапросы поддерживаются гуглом:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/referen...
но эта таблица тогда противоречит документу (см. тег style):
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
кому верить?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pechkin.com](https://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/268527/) говорит:

> В частности, медиазапросы не работают в Gmail. Несмотря на
>   периодически появляющиеся слухи о грядущем добавлении поддержки этой
>   технологии, пока никаких подвижек в этом направлении нет.

[Там же, решения этой проблемы.](https://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/268527/)

Попробуйте протестировать с помощью [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/).

Отправьте тестовое письмо себе на *gmail*, либо другой почтовый клиент, какой хотели бы проверить. И откройте письмо с мобильного устройства.